# Can I put multiple X windows into a single larger window?

Tags: x11, window-management

Say my main process spawns a couple windows. I'd like to group them in a session-leader master window (a just-the-frame minidesktop for the window group if you will). What can I do to achieve this?

#### More details:

I've been playing around with [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/), and I'm curious as to whether my script could create multiple zenity (or other) windows and group them together within a main window, allowing me to move or close all the generated subwindows at once.

Comment: I know this thread is quite old, but you could also try [guish](https://gitlab.com/phranz/guish)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set up an X server inside an X server using [`Xephyr`](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/Xephyr/). You can create a window on your screen which displays the contents of a new X display:

```
Xephyr :1
```

To start with, that will be empty. You can launch an application or applications pointed at that new display:

```
DISPLAY=:1 some-application
```

All windows that arise from that application will be displayed inside the Xephyr window.

[Xnest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest) is an older rendition of the same idea, which doesn't support the same range of X extensions but is more widely available. You launch it the same way: `Xnest :1`. Both programs support a number of command-line options to configure them more specifically.

In either case, you will probably want to launch a window manager inside the nested server as well, because otherwise your interaction options are pretty limited. You can start another instance of your current window manager inside or use a different one, in the same way that you launch the application: `DISPLAY=:1 twm &`.

You can make as many of these subdisplays as you want, using a different number each time. It's possible to script the whole thing up:

```
Xephyr :1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
some-application &
some-other-application &
```

When you close the Xephyr window, all of the applications trying to use it will get an X error and (generally) terminate with something like:

> ```
> Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1
> ```

This is an error exit, just like if you <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Backspace</kbd> out of your main X server, but it does terminate everything at once.

Comment: With Xnest I ran into the resizing problem described in its manual which makes it unfeasible. Xephyr seems to handle that excellently, though it completely crashed the host X server once I was playing with it and it normally doesn't crash (hopefully, that was just a fluke). The inner windows are easily resizable with wmctrl. Enforcing relative sizes on inner windows shouldn't be a problem either. Marco/metacity seems to be a better choice of a window manager as it doesn't add menus and a background. All in all, Xephyr seems like a feasible way write apps composed of related subwindows. Thanks.

Comment: Xephyr sounds like overkill; it starts a whole new X server! [`XReparentWindow`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-and-session-manager/XReparentWindow.html) (and the [XEmbed protocol](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html)) are much more performant, though I can't point to an easy-to-use wrapper. Here's [an XEmbed example for GTK](https://gist.github.com/bert/809126).

Comment: @Anko: Xephyr (and Xnest) are moderately expensive, but they are also existing tools - if you were planning on writing a program to do it, this would be on SO, not here. I'm not aware of any tool that focuses on using XEmbed for this purpose, and the automation requirements for e.g. new windows would be pretty high in any case. If you know of one that does it, though, that would be useful, and I'd like to know about it too!